# Installing ubuntu on Clean Mac Intel / new HDD

Tags: live-cd

It would seem like this has been asked and answered million times before! But none of those are really working, some where along the way all the solutions are diverging or very generalized!

I tried and tried various How to's on this awesome website, before ASKING!

LSS...

- Have a Fully equipped Mac Intel (Model No: Mac Pro A1186 / 64-bit) and a Brand New HDD. I would like to install Ubuntu on this. I also have a windows 7 machine to help me with!
- No Mac OS / no partitions (EFI and such...) created on the new HDD.

Q1. Which version of ubuntu installer would I choose to make Live cd / usb? The below link says "desktop-amd 64" really for Intel mac??
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Q2. How do (Should?) I create the EFi partition? How can I do that on windows 7?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!
-AB

Comment: What is the actual model number of your Mac? Some older Intel Macs use 32-bit EFI, which means only 32-bit OSes can be installed.

Comment: Model No: Mac Pro A1186 (it is 64-bit system)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took so long to get back to you!

A1:

Yes, you want the ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso. I'm not entirely sure why the Linux community refers to all 64-bits as "amd64" exactly. However, rest assured that the "amd64" variant simply means "64-bit" and will work on any 64-bit AMD or Intel processor (internally, they're pretty much the exact same thing).

A2: Yes, you can create an EFI partition from Windows 7.

1. Type 'diskpart' into the start menu search and press enter
2. Use the following sequence of command to set up your EFI disk:

   ```
   list (take note of the disk you want to use. mine was the second disk, #1 in my VM)
   select disk [disk number]
   list partition (just to make sure you have the right disk selected, it should show no partitions)
   convert gpt
   select partition 1
   delete partition override
   create partition efi size=100
   ```

Now you should be all ready for an Ubuntu install! Just use the "Use entire disk" option when the installer asks and you should be done.

Comment: 14.04 ?? It is EOL since 2019

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the Linux community that refers to  amd64. This is an official designation and a reminder that while Intel was wandering off in search of 64-bit goodness into the wasteland of Itanium, it was AMD that pioneered this sane extension of the Intel instruction set.

--
Chris